Mapping list of pure functions to list elementwise
Like multiplication of lists, could I get {11, 22} from list of pure functions {(#+1)&,(#+2)&} and argument list {10,20} using Thread function or MapThread etc? ※From a pure function {(#1+1),(#2+2)}& and sequence [10,20],I could get {11,22} as below.
{(#1+1),(#2+2)}& [10,20]  (*{11,22};from a pure function and sequence*)
(*getting {11,22} from {(#+1)&,(#+2)&} and {11, 22} ?*)


I'm not sure whether I understand, but you are probably looking for Apply: {(#1 + 1), (#2 + 2)} & @@ {10, 20}.

Or just # + {1, 2} &@{10, 20}

MapThread[Compose, {{(# + 1) &, (# + 2) &}, {10, 20}}]

Since the Compose function is outdated:
MapThread[Construct, {{(# + 1) &, (# + 2) &}, {10, 20}}]

Also:
Inner[Construct, {(# + 1) &, (# + 2) &}, {10, 20}, List]


{11, 22}


Thank you for your answer. ※I 've learned that the Construct function can augment pure function and argument. (And I also found that function name can be uesd as arguments as usual expression according to doc( function operators) as  myConstruct[f_,x_]:=f[x])

A simple way would be to use Threaded
{10, 20} + Threaded[{1, 2}]

(* 11, 22 *) 

Another possibility:
Query[{1 -> (# + 1 &), 2 -> (# + 2 &)}][{10, 20}]

(* {11, 22} *) 

The above uses RightComposition and MapAt 'under the hood'
Query[{1 -> (# + 1 &), 2 -> (# + 2 &)}] // Normal

(MapAt[#1 + 2 &, 2]/*MapAt[#1 + 1 &, 1 *) 


Also MapThread[Splice[{# + 1, #2 + 2}] &, Transpose[{{10, 20}}]]
